# Exporting null values from Matlab table to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, matlab, null

I'm trying to export a Matlab table containing "null" values into a SQL Server DB, without any success. Here are my DB settings in Matlab (setdbprefs command):

```
          NullNumberRead: 'NaN'
         NullNumberWrite: 'NaN'
          NullStringRead: 'null'
         NullStringWrite: 'null'
```

And two example scripts to create the test case.
To create the DB structure:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [TestDB]
GO

USE [TestDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [Field1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Field2] [smallint] NULL,
    [Field3] [int] NULL,
    [Field4] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Field5] [datetime] NULL,
    [Field6] [datetime] NULL,
    [Field7] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [CreatedOn_DF]  DEFAULT     (getdate()),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Field1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

To insert a row from Matlab into DB:

```
% Connect to MS SQL Server Database
conn = database('TestDB','','','Vendor','Microsoft SQL Server',...
    'Server','localhost','AuthType','Windows',...
    'PortNumber',1433);

% Build record to Export (note that Field1 and Field7 are missing because
% are already generated by destination server)
R = struct('Field2', 1,...
    'Field3', 10,...
    'Field4', 'abc',...
    'Field5', '2016-01-01 00:00:00',...
    'Field6', NaN);

% Transform to Table
R = struct2table(R);

% Export to Database
datainsert(conn, '[TestDB].[dbo].[TestTable]',     R.Properties.VariableNames, R);
```

I get the following error, while it should be allowed by Matlab DB prefs.

> Error using database/datainsert (line 301)
>       Unable to insert element in row 1 column 5, NaN. Timestamp format must    be    yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Comment: There is No `NaN` is sql server, try to replace it with `Null`.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried but without success. Moreover I tried to change Matlab R/W setting with setdbprefs.

Comment: A workarround will be to export all your data in Varchars and then try to create a new table in SQL Server with correct types. Sorry this is all I can think of.